# In iOS pwa mode setting meta theme-color has an unexpected transition effect, is it possible to disable it?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, frontend, progressive-web-apps

I am using iOS 15.2.1 (iPhone). I am woking on a site featuring PWA, and using the theme color feature with meta tag `<meta name="theme-color" content="orange" />`.

I noticed that when in PWA mode(add the website to homescreen), setting theme color using js(change the content of meta) will cause a transition of color to happen.

Some code I used

```
const meta = document.querySelector('meta[name=theme-color]')
meta.setAttribute('content', '#333333')
```

This will change theme-color from orange to #333333. However when the color in the top panel of the device changes, it has some sort of easing effect. I don't want that. Disabling transition on html and body tag won't help. But when it opens in mobile safari directly, changing the meta theme-color will cause the color of the top panel to change immediately. Is it possible to disable the transition effect in PWA mode?

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anyone know the values of the default transition?